# ConnectionRefused when trying to connect to hadoop using cloudera

Tags: hadoop

When I try to do a command that connects with hadoop I get an exception

For example:

command: hdfs dfs -ls /user/cloudera

result:ls: Call From quickstart.cloudera/10.0.2.15 to quickstart.cloudera:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

In addition, when I used such commands before, I did not have that problem.

Thanks

Comment: Which user are you running as ? Did you try a different user ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to Cloudera manager in the browser. Usually this is bookmarked on Firefox as "Cloudera manager". Login "cloudera/clousera". Then start "HDFS" service. The "hadoop fs" commands should start working now.